# Adding product variation to the shopping cart (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out how woocommerce add product variation to the shopping cart via url.
I'm print out the cart on the home page with this code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[woocommerce_cart]");
```

I have a multi step attributes selection. So, the idea is, when the user click on the attribute button in the last step, the product variation should be added to the shopping cart via ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '#step-4 input', function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.org/?add-to-cart=456',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#cart-section').replaceWith($(data).find('#cart-section'));
    }
});
});
```

I found the article, which refers to this:
 http://example.org/cart/?add-to-cart=123&variation_id=456&attribute_pa_colour=black

But for some reason it doesn't work for me at all.
What is work is this '/?add-to-cart=456', but in this case the $cart_item array, which used in the cart.php template:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => **$cart_item** ) {
        $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], **$cart_item**, $cart_item_key );
        $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], **$cart_item**, $cart_item_key );
```

contains the empty string with key ['variation'], but ['variation'] should be a key of an array to use it in the get_item_data() method (cart.php template):

```
echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ).
```

Can you give me any advise?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I've solved this problem by adding to the end of url "&quantity=1".

Comment: Also see [this tutorial](http://www.remicorson.com/add-woocommerce-variable-product-with-variations-to-cart/)